# Can I ignore onAnimatedValueUpdate warning?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have multiple stacks inside navigatior in react-native app and on material top tabs when you are on first tab and try to slide right or when you are on last tab and try to slide left I am getting this warning:

```
 WARN  Sending `onAnimatedValueUpdate` with no listeners registered.
```

this is only happening on iOS, on android everything working fine. Top tabs are nested inside bottom tabs stack.

Can I ignore this warning or it will cause crashes in production version?